# How to Guess schema in Mysqlinput on the fly in Talend

Tags: mysql, schema, talend, jobs

I've build a job that copy data from a mysql db table to b mysql table.
The table columns are the same except sometimes a new column can be added in table a db.

i want to retrieve all the columns from a to b but only those that exists in table b. i was able to put in the query specific select colume statment that exists in table b like:

```
select coulmn1,column2,columns3... from table a
```

the issue is if i add a new column in b that matches a the talend job schema in Mysqlinput should be changed as well cause i work with build in type.

Is there a way to force the schema columns during the job running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a subscription version of Talend, you can use the dynamic column type. You can define a single column for your input of type "Dynamic" and map it to a column of the same type in your output component. This will dynamically get columns from table a and map them to the same columns in table b.  Here's an [example](https://help.talend.com/reader/NNO~fmVQU4rlkF9Depfdxw/gI28uiZ5glG1gkVCI1lXNg).
If you are using Talend Open Studio, things get a little trickier as Talend expects a list of columns for the input and output components that need to be defined at design time.

Here's a solution I put together to work around this limitation.

[image]

The idea is to list all table a's columns that are present in table b. Then convert it to a comma separated list of columns, in my example `id,Theme,name` and store it in a global variable `COLUMN_LIST`. A second output of the tMap builds the same list of columns, but this time putting single quotes between columns (so as they can be used as parameters to the `CONCAT` function later), then add single quotes to the beginning and end, like so: `"'", id,"','",Theme,"','",name,"'"` and store it in a global variable `CONCAT_LIST`.

On the next subjob, I query `table a` using the `CONCAT` function, giving it the list of columns to be concatenated `CONCAT_LIST`, thus retrieving each record in a single column like so `'value1', 'value2',..etc`

Then at last I execute an `INSERT` query against `table b`, by specifying the list of columns given by the global variable `COLUMN_LIST`, and the values to be inserted as a single string resulting from the `CONCAT` function (`row6.values`).

This solution is generic, if you replace your table names by context variables, you can use it to copy data from any MySQL table to another table.

Comment: I do use Talend Open Studio :(

Comment: Do your tables often change structure ?

Comment: Do your tables a and b reside in different databases ? If they are on the same database, I can suggest a solution.

Comment: they are different