# Loadind multiple table from source into multiple table into target in Talend

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have around 25 tables to load to target with same structure and which use the same logic for loading. I have prepared one job which does that, but it's a long process to design all the tables.
Is there any way to pass the table name and load to target, basically a small job (in size).
I am using Talend open studio.

Answer (score 2):

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48250956/899863) to a similar question where I proposed a generic solution for loading a MySQL table to another MySQL table.
You just need to modify the queries that retrieve the tables' metadata (columns) depending on your database type.